# iptables drops some 80 port connections every 12 sec

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having strange issue. The problem is, that syslog contains **(every 12 seconds)** one logged/blocked connection, for example this one belogs to googlebot:

```
iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=66.249.66.52 DST=<MY_SERVER_IP> LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x40 TTL=55 ID=49488 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47902 DPT=80 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

or this one to Opera Mini:

```
iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=141.0.8.219 DST=<MY_SERVER_IP> LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x40 TTL=58 ID=41251 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50426 DPT=80 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Iptables rules (removed ssh rules):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sat Sep 29 14:25:22 2012
*filter
:INPUT DROP [28:2605]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [54305:39093682]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 29 14:25:22 2012
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Looks like this is the 'googlebot' for what that's worth.crawl-66-249-66-52.googlebot.com.

Comment: This time iptables blocks random ip's, for example another one is 141.0.8.219, that belogs to Opera Mini

Comment: It's not blocking anything, you've just told it to log up to 5 entries/minute for any traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the third INPUT rule, which is logging samples of all traffic.

It's not actually blocking the traffic at all, the log message just gives you the impression it is.

From the iptables manage

> limit
>
> ```
>   This  module  matches  at  a  limited  rate  using a token bucket filter.  A rule using this extension will match until this limit is reached
>
>   (unless the ‘!’ flag is used).  It can be used in combination with the LOG target to give limited logging, for example.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how can I log all blocked connections?

Comment: You need a log line and a deny line at the end of the INPUT table. Can't really put that in a comment. My advice would be to download fwbuilder ( a great GUI ) and use that to build you rule base.